# Mysql container not starting up on Kubernetes

Tags: mysql, docker, kubernetes

I was using [this](https://hub.docker.com/layers/bitnami/mysql/5.7/images/sha256-87d11d41343c5404073f13b555e2849db4cb975f10e9b84ff4054242f1f7dade?context=explore) image to run my application in `docker-compose`. However, when I run the same on a Kubernetes cluster I get the error

```
[ERROR] Could not open file '/opt/bitnami/mysql/logs/mysqld.log' for error logging: Permission denied
```

Here's my deployment file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.21.0 ()
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: common-db
  name: common-db
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: common-db
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: kompose convert
        kompose.version: 1.21.0 ()
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: common-db
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD
          value: "yes"
        - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
          value: "common-development"
        - name: MYSQL_REPLICATION_MODE
          value: "master"
        - name: MYSQL_REPLICATION_PASSWORD
          value: "repl_password"
        - name: MYSQL_REPLICATION_USER
          value: "repl_user"
        image: bitnami/mysql:5.7
        imagePullPolicy: ""
        name: common-db
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 0
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: 512Mi
            cpu: 500m
          limits:
            memory: 512Mi
            cpu: 500m
        volumeMounts:
          - name: common-db-initdb
            mountPath: /opt/bitnami/mysql/conf/my_custom.cnf
      volumes:
        - name: common-db-initdb
          configMap:
            name: common-db-config
      serviceAccountName: ""

status: {}
```

The config map has the config `my.cnf` data. Any pointers on where I could be going wrong? Specially if the same image works in the `docker-compose`?

Comment: if you can please check file permission for this path `/opt/bitnami/mysql/logs/mysqld.log`. you can change permission if required using `init container`.

Comment: i think it's due to there is no folder for logs in volume mount or else permission issue to write logs in volume mount.

Comment: https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mariadb/issues/136#issuecomment-354644226

Comment: https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/mysql

Comment: @HarshManvar I have not mounted any volume to the logs directory, shouldn't the logs be written to the container's volume?

Comment: yes it should be in contain's volume but as it's giving permission error so i think `subpath` may resolve issues, however, i will suggest using helm chart only as it is also using `init container` at starting.

Comment: @HarshManvar, do you mean the `subPath` as posted in the answer by @hoque? Isn't that for a different file in a different directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the file permission using `init container` as in official bitnami helm chart they are also updating file permissions and managing security context.

helm chart : https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/mysql/templates/master-statefulset.yaml

**UPDATE** :

```
 initContainers:
      - command:
        - /bin/bash
        - -ec
        - |
          chown -R 1001:1001 /bitnami/mysql
        image: docker.io/bitnami/minideb:buster
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: volume-permissions
        resources: {}
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 0
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /bitnami/mysql
          name: data
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1001
        runAsUser: 1001
      serviceAccount: mysql
```

Comment: I tried the initContainer but I don't think I'm quite sure what should the command be in my case. While helm is certainly useful I cannot use that in the internal organisation Kubernetes cluster. Could you elaborate on `subPath`?  or how could I change the permissions in the initContainer for my case?

Comment: updated init container hope it will work. `subpath` use for hare one volume for multiple uses in a single Pod.

Comment: @VishakhaLall check this is out : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1gHozxw2yY7K3SSd_f04m5FbQWINnobHA?usp=sharing

Comment: these files working for GKE however have to use subpath. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1gHozxw2yY7K3SSd_f04m5FbQWINnobHA?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use subpath. To know details about subpath click [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath)

```
volumeMounts:
  - name: common-db-initd
    mountPath: /opt/bitnami/mysql/conf/my_custom.cnf
    subPath: my_custom.cnf
```

Also, you can install bitnami mysql using helm [chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/mysql) easily.

Comment: This didn't work, while the `my_custom.cnf` file was loaded, I still get the error. I did check out the helm chart, however I am deploying on a private Kubernetes cluster where I am unable to use the helm chart.