# MySQL on Kubernetes not starting after re-deploy on existing PV - 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, kubernetes

I have an issue with the mysql/mysql-server:8.0 (for arm64) image, being deployed on home home k3s node. When I don't use a PV, the instance works fine. However, if I use a persistent volume and claim, the server can no longer probe the instance to check if it's up, and I can't log in as root anymore.

Config map:

```
resource "kubernetes_manifest" "sql_config_map" {
  manifest = {
    "apiVersion" = "v1"
    "data" = {
      "my.cnf" = <<-EOT
      [mysqld]
      default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
      skip-host-cache
      skip-name-resolve
      datadir=/var/lib/mysql
      socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
      secure-file-priv=/var/lib/mysql-files
      user=mysql
      pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
      EOT
    }
    "kind" = "ConfigMap"
    "metadata" = {
      "labels" = {
        "app" = local.db_name
      }
      "name" = "my-cnf"
      "namespace" = local.namespace_name
    }
  }
}
```

DB Deployment:

```
resource "kubernetes_manifest" "ghost_db" {
  depends_on = [kubernetes_persistent_volume_claim.ghost_db, kubernetes_secret.secrets]
  manifest = {
    "apiVersion" = "apps/v1"
    "kind" = "Deployment"
    "metadata" = {
      "labels" = {
        "app" = local.app_name
      }
      "name" = local.db_name
      "namespace" = local.namespace_name
    }
    "spec" = {
      "replicas" = 1
      "selector" = {
        "matchLabels" = {
          "app" = local.db_name
        }
      }
      "template" = {
        "metadata" = {
          "labels" = {
            "app" = local.db_name
          }
        }
        "spec" = {
          "containers" = [
            {
              "args" = [
                "--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password",
              ]
              "env" = [
                {
                  "name" = "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"
                  "valueFrom" = {
                    "secretKeyRef" = {
                      "key" = "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"
                      "name" = "${local.db_name}-mysql"
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "name" = "MYSQL_DATABASE"
                  "value" = local.db_name
                },
                {
                  "name" = "MYSQL_USER"
                  "value" = local.db_user
                },
                {
                  "name" = "MYSQL_PASSWORD"
                  "valueFrom" = {
                    "secretKeyRef" = {
                      "key" = "MYSQL_PASSWORD"
                      "name" = "${local.db_name}-mysql"
                    }
                  }
                },
              ]
              "image" = "mysql/mysql-server:8.0"
              "imagePullPolicy" = "IfNotPresent"
              "livenessProbe" = {
                "exec" = {
                  "command" = [
                    "sh",
                    "-c",
                    "mysqladmin status -uroot -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD",
                  ]
                }
                "failureThreshold" = 3
                "initialDelaySeconds" = 30
                "periodSeconds" = 10
                "successThreshold" = 1
                "timeoutSeconds" = 1
              }
              "name" = local.db_name
              "ports" = [
                {
                  "containerPort" = 3306
                  "name" = local.db_name
                },
              ]
              "readinessProbe" = {
                "exec" = {
                  "command" = [
                    "sh",
                    "-c",
                    "mysqladmin status -uroot -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD",
                  ]
                }
                "failureThreshold" = 3
                "initialDelaySeconds" = 30
                "periodSeconds" = 10
                "successThreshold" = 1
                "timeoutSeconds" = 1
              }
              "volumeMounts" = [
                {
                  "mountPath" = "/var/lib/mysql"
                  "name" = "${local.db_name}-persistent-storage"
                },
                {
                  "mountPath" = "/etc/my.cnf"
                  "name" = "my-cnf"
                  "subPath" = "my.cnf"
                },
              ]
            },
          ]
          # "initContainers" = [
          #   {
          #     "command" = [
          #       "sh",
          #       "-c",
          #       "chown -R 1001:1001 /var/lib/mysql"
          #     ]
          #     "image" = "busybox:latest"
          #     "imagePullPolicy" = "Always"
          #     "name" = "volume-permissions"
          #     "resources" = {}
          #     "securityContext" = {
          #       "runAsUser" = 0
          #     }
          #     "terminationMessagePath" = "/dev/termination-log"
          #     "terminationMessagePolicy" = "File"
          #     "volumeMounts" = [
          #       {
          #         "mountPath" = "/var/lib/mysql"
          #         "name" = "${local.db_name}-persistent-storage"
          #       },
          #     ]
          #   },
          # ]
          "hostname" = local.db_name
          "subdomain" = local.subdomain
          "nodeSelector" = {
            "kubernetes.io/hostname" = local.nodeSelector_hostname
          }
          "securityContext" = {
            "fsGroup" = 1001
            "runAsUser" = 1001
          }
          "serviceAccountName" = "default"
          "volumes" = [
            {
              "name" = "${local.db_name}-persistent-storage"
              "persistentVolumeClaim" = {
                "claimName" = local.db_name
              }
            },
            {
              "name" = "my-cnf"
              "configMap" = {
                "name" = "my-cnf"
              }
            },
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to use an init container to change the permissions as suggested here [Mysql container not starting up on Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62058982/mysql-container-not-starting-up-on-kubernetes). But I have the same issues:

Error:

```
bash-4.4$ mysqladmin status -uroot -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
mysqladmin: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

MySQL Container Logs:

```
[Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 8.0.26-1.2.4-server
[Entrypoint] Starting MySQL 8.0.26-1.2.4-server
2021-09-27T09:41:12.025060Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010143] [Server] Ignoring user change to '1001' because the user was set to 'mysql' earlier on the command line
2021-09-27T09:41:12.026132Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.26) starting as process 1
2021-09-27T09:41:12.028501Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010122] [Server] One can only use the --user switch if running as root
2021-09-27T09:41:12.033575Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-09-27T09:41:12.194605Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-09-27T09:41:12.340795Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1 is enabled for channel mysql_main
2021-09-27T09:41:12.340934Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013746] [Server] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1.1 is enabled for channel mysql_main
2021-09-27T09:41:12.341892Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-09-27T09:41:12.342070Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-09-27T09:41:12.364915Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2021-09-27T09:41:12.366981Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.26'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

On the node, if I remove the data directory and again re-deploy the deployment it works. It just doesn't seem to re-deploy on the same PV. The use case would be if I move nodes and I want to re-attach the data disk.

Any suggestions? I know people are using the bitnami helm chart with the "volumePermissions.enabled" value, however I can't use the chart because bitnami doesn't have arm64 images yet.

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use?

Comment: It's actually running on K3s.

Comment: Please, provide me [version of Kubernetes](https://www.cloudytuts.com/tutorials/kubernetes/how-to-check-kubernetes-version/), not the the way you set up the cluster.

Comment: Right, sorry it's v1.21.4+k3s1

Comment: Did you see [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445917/connect-failed-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes) with similar problem?

Comment: I don't see how that relevant. My issue is after deploying the same deployment to the same PV, using the same secrets for the password, I can no longer log into the DB. I will try a mysql root password reset.

Comment: Could I ask for PV manifest? Also could you try to login with actual password, not from env variable?